# update 1.1 twitter wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, twitter

Twitter have stopped api 1 in the last few days and as a result 'wp to twitter' has stopped working. There seems little (comprehendible) info on the twitter site for updating to 1.1.v. I deleted the app (or tried another issue) and created a new application (with read and write). I then went to my wordpress plugin and updated the tokens and keys but still get the message

Twitter requires authentication by OAuth. You will need to update your settings to complete installation of WP to Twitter.

Should I just change the wordpress plugin?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have entered your tokens correctly, then it sounds like a bug in the plugin.

Give my plugin a try if you like. http://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/
If you have the same problems I'll try to help.

Comment: The plugin I have is WP posts to be tweeted. Isn't yours tweets to wordpress site? (The plugin worked fine until api 1 deprecated, so it is an issue with the twitter 1.1 compatibility)